# Is the Session object from Python's Requests library thread safe?

Tags: python, thread-safety, connection-pooling, python-requests

Python's popular [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library is said to be thread-safe on its home page, but no further details are given. If I call `requests.session()`, can I then safely pass this object to multiple threads like so:

```
session = requests.session()
for i in xrange(thread_count):
    threading.Thread(
        target=target,
        args=(session,),
        kwargs={}
    )
```

and make requests using the same connection pool in multiple threads?

If so, is this the recommended approach, or should each thread be given its own connection pool? (Assuming the total size of all the individual connection pools summed to the size of what would be one big connection pool, like the one above.) What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: Did you figure out which is better?  I'm currently running into nearly the same question.  I was thinking a new session for each thread so as to not bottleneck all requests in a single connection pool.

Comment: @Marcel Wilson Not exactly. Although for one of my projects where I was using a session object to request the same URL over and over again, I sent the same session object to all of the threads. The application does seem to work, but I am still not sure what the better approach is. Note, though, that my problem was not with bottlenecking the connection pools, but was instead with opening too many connections and sending too many requests at a time.

Comment: Requests is built on top of urllib3. The thread-safety of requests is largely due to the thread-safety of urllib3, the doucmentation for which discusses thread safety in greater detail.

Comment: @dg123 I ended up creating a session in the for loop.  Each thread gets it's own connection pool.

Answer (score 34):

After reviewing the source of [`requests.session`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py), I'm going to say the session object might be thread-safe, depending on the implementation of CookieJar being used.

`Session.prepare_request` reads from `self.cookies`, and `Session.send` calls `extract_cookies_to_jar(self.cookies, ...)`, and that calls `jar.extract_cookies(...)` (`jar` being `self.cookies` in this case).

The source for [Python 2.7's `cookielib`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/cookielib.py#l1635) acquires a lock (`threading.RLock`) while it updates the jar, so it appears to be thread-safe. On the other hand, the [documentation for `cookielib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html) says nothing about thread-safety, so maybe this feature should not be depended on?

UPDATE

If your threads are mutating any attributes of the session object such as `headers`, `proxies`, `stream`, etc. or calling the `mount` method or using the session with the `with` statement, etc. then it is not thread-safe.

Comment: Yet, I assume if you do `my_session.get(url, headers={"something": "something"})` this should not be an issue.

Answer (score 34):

https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1871 implies that Session is not thread-safe, and that at least one maintainer recommends one Session per thread.

I just opened https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2766 to clarify the documentation.

Comment: It looks like this depends on `urllib3` being thread safe, which I don't believe it is based on https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1252

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same question and went to the source code to find a suitable solution for me.
In my opinion Session class generally has various problems.

1. It initializes the default HTTPAdapter in the constructor and leaks it if you mount another one to 'http' or 'https'.
2. HTTPAdapter implementation maintains the connection pool, I think it is not something to create on each Session object instantiation.
3. Session closes HTTPAdapter, thus you can't reuse the connection pool between different Session instances.
4. Session class doesn't seem to be thread safe according to various discussions.
5. HTTPAdapter internally uses the urlib3.PoolManager. And I didn't find any obvious problem related to the thread safety in the source code, so I would rather trust the documentation, which says that urlib3 is thread safe.

As the conclusion from the above list I didn't find anything better than overriding Session class

```
class HttpSession(Session):
    def __init__(self, adapter: HTTPAdapter):
        self.headers = default_headers()
        self.auth = None
        self.proxies = {}
        self.hooks = default_hooks()
        self.params = {}
        self.stream = False
        self.verify = True
        self.cert = None
        self.max_redirects = DEFAULT_REDIRECT_LIMIT
        self.trust_env = True
        self.cookies = cookiejar_from_dict({})
        self.adapters = OrderedDict()
        self.mount('https://', adapter)
        self.mount('http://', adapter)

    def close(self) -> None:
        pass
```

And creating the connection factory like:

```
class HttpSessionFactory:
    def __init__(self,
             pool_max_size: int = DEFAULT_CONNECTION_POOL_MAX_SIZE,
             retry: Retry = DEFAULT_RETRY_POLICY):
        self.__http_adapter = HTTPAdapter(pool_maxsize=pool_max_size, max_retries=retry)

    def session(self) -> Session:
        return HttpSession(self.__http_adapter)

    def close(self):
        self.__http_adapter.close()
```

Finally, somewhere in the code I can write:

```
with self.__session_factory.session() as session:
    response = session.get(request_url)
```

And all my session instances will reuse the same connection pool.
And somewhere at the end when the application stops I can close the HttpSessionFactory.
Hope this will help somebody.

Comment: 2. I agree with you but I guess the requests library has to make some stricter assumptions about use cases beyond ours. 3. Only if you do close the Session, which is unnecessary precisely for reusable HTTP adapters. Do not use Sessions as context managers because of tradition!

Comment: Overall, your snippet does not address Session thread-unsafety or avoid thread-blocking, which would mainly come, AFAIU, from the cookie jar and the redirection cache. It is simply about reusing the connection pool cross-thread. This is nice but this is not about thread-safety. Also, you might be interested in this simpler approach to the same idea: global adapter instead of a session factory https://stackoverflow.com/a/73094972/11715259

Comment: > 4. Session class doesn't seem to be thread safe according to various discussions. — which discussions? Could you link some?