# What is the recommended way of sharing a HTTP connection pool between threads with requests?

Tags: python, thread-safety, python-requests, connection-pooling, python-multithreading

I'm working in an environment where web applications fork processes on demand and each process has its own thread pool to service web requests.  The threads may need to issue HTTPS requests to outside services, and the requests library is currently used to do so.  When requests usage was first added, it was used naively by creating a new `requests.Session` and `requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter` for each request, or even by simply calling `requests.get` or `requests.post` on demand.  The problem that arises is that a new connection is established each time instead of potentially taking advantage of HTTP persistent connections.  A potential fix would be to use a connection pool, but what is the recommended way of sharing a HTTP connection pool between threads when using the requests library?  Is there one?

The first thought would be to share a single `requests.Session`, but that currently not safe, as described in "[Is the Session object from Python's Requests library thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188044/is-the-session-object-from-pythons-requests-library-thread-safe)" and "[Document threading contract for Session class](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/2766)". Is it safe and sufficient to have a single global `requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter` that is shared between `requests.Sessions`s that are created on demand in each thread?  According to "[Our use of urllib3's ConnectionPools is not threadsafe.](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1871)", even that may not be a valid use.  Only needing to connect to a small number of distinct remote endpoints may allow it to be a viable approach regardless.

Comment: Does it really have to be requests? I do it using urllib2. I construct an object that is tasked with getting/posting/whatever to server with added useful methods. Then I make a pool of those and control the data flow from outside, which is to say, from main thread. It is easy. If you don't mind urllib2 instead of requests I'll post some code.

Comment: @Dalen I would like to try to find whether there is a requests-based solution first, in order to minimize the amount of code changes required if there is indeed one.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is existing way to do this in requests. But you can modify my code to encapsulate requests session() instead of standard urllib2.

This is my code that I use when I want to get data from multiple sites at the same time:

```
# Following code I keep in file named do.py
# It can be use to perform any number of otherwise blocking IO operations simultaneously
# Results are available to you when all IO operations are completed.
# Completed means either IO finished successfully or an exception got raised.
# So when all tasks are completed, you pick up results.
# Usage example:
# >>> import do
# >>> results = do.simultaneously([
# ...     (func1, func1_args, func1_kwargs),
# ...     (func2, func2_args, func2_kwargs), ...])
# >>> for x in results:
# ...     print x
# ...
from thread import start_new_thread as thread
from thread import allocate_lock
from collections import deque
from time import sleep

class Task:
    """A task's thread holder. Keeps results or exceptions raised.
    This could be a bit more robustly implemented using
    threading module.
    """
    def __init__ (self, func, args, kwargs, pool):
        self.func    = func
        self.args    = args
        self.kwargs  = kwargs
        self.result  = None
        self.done    = 0
        self.started = 0
        self.xraised = 0
        self.tasks = pool
        pool.append(self)
        self.allow = allocate_lock()
        self.run()

    def run (self):
        thread(self._run,())

    def _run (self):
        self.allow.acquire() # Prevent same task from being started multiple times
        self.started = 1
        self.result  = None
        self.done    = 0
        self.xraised = 0
        try:
            self.result = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except Exception, e:
            e.task = self # Keep reference to the task in an exception
                          # This way we can access original task from caught exception
            self.result = e
            self.xraised = 1
        self.done = 1
        self.allow.release()

    def wait (self):
        while not self.done:
            try: sleep(0.001)
            except: break

    def withdraw (self):
        if not self.started: self.run()
        if not self.done: self.wait()
        self.tasks.remove(self)
        return self.result

    def remove (self):
        self.tasks.remove(self)

def simultaneously (tasks, xraise=0):
    """Starts all functions within iterable <tasks>.
    Then waits for all to be finished.
    Iterable <tasks> may contain a subiterables with:
        (function, [[args,] kwargs])
    or just functions. These would be called without arguments.
    Returns an iterator that yields result of each called function.
    If an exception is raised within a task the Exception()'s instance will be returned unless
     is 1 or True. Then first encountered exception within results will be raised.
    Results will start to yield after all funcs() either return or raise an exception.
    """
    pool = deque()
    for x in tasks:
        func   = lambda: None
        args   = ()
        kwargs = {}
        if not isinstance(x, (tuple, list)):
            Task(x, args, kwargs, pool)
            continue
        l = len(x)
        if l: func = x[0]
        if l>1:
            args = x[1]
            if not isinstance(args, (tuple, list)): args = (args,)
        if l>2:
            if isinstance(x[2], dict):
                kwargs = x[2]
        Task(func, args, kwargs, pool)
    for t in pool: t.wait()
    while pool:
        t = pool.popleft()
        if xraise and t.xraised:
            raise t.result
        yield t.result

# So, I do this using urllib2, you can do it using requests if you want.
from urllib2 import URLError, HTTPError, urlopen
import do

class AccessError(Exception):
    """Raised if server rejects us because we bombarded same server with multiple connections in too small time slots."""
    pass

def retrieve (url):
    try:
        u = urlopen(url)
        r = u.read()
        u.close()
        return r
    except HTTPError, e:
        msg = "HTTPError %i - %s" % (e.code, e.msg)
        t = AccessError()
        if e.code in (401, 403, 429):
            msg += " (perhaps you're making too many calls)"
            t.reason = "perhaps you are making too many calls"
        elif e.code in (502, 504):
            msg += " (service temporarily not available)"
            t.reason = "service temporarily not available"
        else: t.reason = e.msg
        t.args = (msg,)
        t.message = msg
        t.msg = e.msg; t.code = e.code
        t.orig = e
        raise t
    except URLError, e:
        msg = "URLError %s - %s (%s)" % (str(e.errno), str(e.message), str(e.reason))
        t = AccessError(msg)
        t.reason = str(e.reason)
        t.msg = str(t.message)
        t.code = e.errno
        t.orig = e
        raise t
    except: raise

urls = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.amazon.com", "http://stackoverflow.com", "http://blah.blah.sniff-sniff"]
retrieval = []
for u in urls:
    retrieval.append((retrieve, u))

x = 0
for data in do.simultaneously(retrieval):
    url = urls[x]
    if isinstance(data, Exception):
        print url, "not retrieved successfully!\nThe error is:"
        print data
    else:
        print url, "returned", len(data), "characters!!\nFirst 100:"
        print data[:100]
    x += 1

# If you need persistent HTTP, you tweak the retrieve() function to be able to hold the connection open.
# After retrieving currently requested data You save opened connections in a global dict() with domains as keys.
# When the next retrieve is called and the domain already has an opened connection, you remove the connection from dict (to prevent any other retrieve grabbing it in the middle of nowhere), then you use it
# to send a new request if possible. (If it isn't timed out or something), if connection broke, you just open a new one.
# You will probably have to introduce some limits if you will be using multiple connections to same server at once.
# Like no more than 4 connections to same server at once, some delays between requests and so on.
# No matter which approach to multithreading you will choose (something like I propose or some other mechanism) thread safety is in trouble because HTTP is serialized protocol.
# You send a request, you await the answer. After you receive whole answer, then you can make a new request if HTTP/1.1 is used and connection is being kept alive.
# If your thread tries to send a new request during the data download a general mess will occur.
# So you design your system to open as much connections as possible, but always wait for one to be free before reusing it. Thats a trick here.
# As for any other part of requests being thread unsafe for some reason, well, you should check the code to see which calls exactly should be kept atomic and then use a lock. But don't put it in a block where major IO is occurring or it will be as you aren't using threads at all.
```