# Global requests.Session object drawbacks

Tags: python, python-requests

I recently found global `request.Session()` declaration. E.g:

```py
# one of many files
import requests

g_session = requests.Session()

def some_foo():
    return g_session.post('https://example.com', data={'key': 'value'}

# rest of the code
```

From [docs](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects):

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance, and will use urllib3’s connection pooling. So if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase (see HTTP persistent connection).

So as i understand:

**the benefits** are no need to open new connection, and it can be reused

**the downsides** are supporting the same connection and keeping memory occupied

---

**Is there anything else?**

I've never seen such global declaration. Most of the times *sessions* are used in context manager way, or reuse object in same function/block code, but not globally.

<sub>Possible relevant info: it's part of django application.</sub>

Comment: it keeps cookies between requests - so you don't have to copy them - ie. login cookies. You can set headers in session and all requests will use them - ie. `user-agent`. Frankly, I never used session in context manager, I use it only in this way.

Comment: How is supporting the same session a downside...? There's no continuous connection, it just preserves state, like cookies, just like furas mentioned.

"Occupied memory" isn't that either, if it really was such a big deal, you wouldn't be using a language like Python to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

One drawback is that it is unclear whether Session is thread-safe, since the `requests` documentation does not mention it. A thread from 2013 suggests that it is not: [Is the Session object from Python's Requests library thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18188044/309483) but it links an Urllib3 issue that has been resolved and closed: [PoolManager is not thread-safe](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1252)

You could make your session thread-local, but if you are accessing your Session from worker threads (e.g. in a HTTP server like Flask with uwsgi), you'll could end up with `worker_threads*requests_pool_size` connections, which seems excessive.