# make a method with requests.get() thread-safe

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

EDIT
So my B class receives messages for a telegram bot, this is the code, for each message received call the function in class A

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['get'])
def get(message):
    uid = message.chat.id
    #url that should return a 404 error
    response = get_response(url)
    #if I get a "get" command while the previous message received is still trying to execute the requests
    #the requests do not return a 404 message as it should (I know this because I deliberately pass a link that returns an error 404)
    if response.status_code == 404:
        bot.send_message(uid,"404")
        return
    else:
        #other
```

this is the code of the class A function

```
def get_response(url):
ua = UserAgent()
while (True):

    for i in range(1, len(proxies)):
        proxy = next(proxy_pool)
        try:
            header = {'User-Agent': str(ua.random)}
            response = requests.get(url, headers=header, proxies={"http": proxy, "https": proxy}, verify=False,
                                    timeout=10)
            return response
        except:
           print("Skipping. Connnection error")

    #other conditions to break the while loop

return None
```

This method is called by other classes B and C and by different threads, the problem is that I think the `requests.get()` is not a threadsafe function and therefore does not work well when it is called by multiple threads at the same time. For example if I call `requests.get()` simultaneously from multiple threads with links that should return a 404 error, this error is not returned, while it is returned if the call to `requests.get()` is made individually.
So how to make this method thread safe and work properly if it is called by multiple threads?

Comment: I don't see any reason that `requests.get` shouldn't be thread safe. For starters, with the GIL only one thread will be in the code at a time. Most of its execution time is going to be blocking on I/O. Are you sure it's not an issue having to do with the sites you're requesting? If you're sharing a session amongst threads, [there is cause for concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188044/is-the-session-object-from-pythons-requests-library-thread-safe) but that's not the case here.

Comment: A [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: Have you see  grequests ? https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests

Comment: @ggorlen code updated

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar I need to use proxy, timeout and headers,  does grequests.get() support them

Comment: Thanks, although this still isn't really reproducible unfortunately. I should be able to copy+paste, hit run, see the 404s.

Comment: @james I think yes ..  https://gist.github.com/windj007/d49391fccc1cf6e22856ebaabf892fc6