# Requests Session asynchronous usage?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests

My current code creates the separate `Session` object for every request through the `.get()` method:

`content_getters.py` (the relevant part):

```
def get_page_content(link: str) -> bytes:
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; "
                             "Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) "
                             "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                             "Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"}

    response = requests.get(link, headers=headers)

    html = response.content.decode("utf-8")

    if response.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        raise ConnectionError("Page", link, "returned status code",
                              response.status_code)

    return response.content

def parse_single_page(link):
    content = get_page_conent(link)
    # rest of very long function
```

`main.py`:

```
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

from content_getters import get_page_content, extract_links, parse_single_page

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MAX_THREADS = 30

    # get links
    html: str = get_page_content(
        "https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/bestiary-hub/monsters-by-cr/") \
        .decode("utf-8")

    links = extract_links(html)

    num_threads = min(MAX_THREADS, len(links))
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_threads) as executor:
        # asynchronous, threads will return results when they finish their
        # own work
        results = [result for result
                   in executor.map(parse_single_page, links)]
```

`requests` docs ([link](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/)) state that "if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase". I suppose that my separate calls to the `.get()` method create separate `Session` objects for each call, which can be faster.

**Question:** Is the `Session` object synchronous (sequential) for all requests made with it? Will I still get asynchronous requests if I use the same `Session` object for all threads in `concurrent.futures.thread.ThreadPoolExecutor`, instead of 1 `Session` per thread as I'm doing now?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188044/is-the-session-object-from-pythons-requests-library-thread-safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, `Session` is not thread-safe, you can check the [issue](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2766) discussion on Github.

For your case, I would highly recommend to look toward the `asyncio` and the `aiohttp` module, where you will have freedom to pass around a `session` since everything will be in one thread. It also won't induce as much overhead as the `multithreading`. As they say:

> Use asyncio when you can, use threads when you must

The [documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) on `aiohttp`.

Comment: Very interesting, I completely forgot about the asyncio, thanks!

Comment: @qalis it is awesome! May have a bit of learning curve, but totally worth it. Would suggest this [article](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) to check before official documentation, which is quite verbose.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/), `requests.Session` uses `urllib3`'s connection pooling
for the sessions. And as per `urllib3`'s [documentation](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.connectionpool.html#module-urllib3.connectionpool), it is a thread-safe system now.

When the question was originally posted it probably wasn't, but in a GitHub [comment](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2766#issuecomment-1600607248), it was most likely made thread-safe for good.

Comment: Just adding a link to the commit based on the comment you posted https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/2661