# faster processing of a for loop with put requests python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have a json file - that i am reading and processing each element due to the api and the payload that is required.

I am looking for ways to speed this up through multi processing / concurrency - not for sure the proper approach.  I think either of those would work as they are individual request updating a specific role within the API. The calls can be run concurrently without impacting the role itself.

the function that i currently have iterates through the following:

newapproach.py

```
import requests
import json
#from multiprocessing import Pool
import urllib3
import cpack_utility
from cpack_utility import classes
#import concurrent.futures
import time
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
def update_role(data):
    url, header, verifySSL = mApi.role()
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers.update(header)
    def update_role_permissions():
        start = time.time()
        for k,v in permissions_roleprivs.items():
            perm_code = v["permissionCode"]
            perm_access = v["access"]
            payload = json.dumps(
                {"permissionCode": perm_code, "access": perm_access}
            )
            result = session.put(url, verify=verifySSL, headers=header, data=payload)
            response = result.json()
            logger.debug(response)
        end = time.time()
        print(f"Time to complete: {round(end - start, 2)}")
    update_role_permissions()

def main(file):
    global mApi 
    global logger
    logger = cpack_utility.logging.get_logger("role")
    mApi = classes.morphRequests_config()

    with open(file, 'r') as f:
      data = f.read()
      data = json.loads(data)
      update_role(data)

    f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The length of time right now is around 60 seconds to process all of the required payloads that need sent.

```
logs
2022-06-20 14:39:16,925:88:update_role:update_role_permissions:DEBUG:{'success': True, 'access': 'none'}
2022-06-20 14:39:17,509:88:update_role:update_role_permissions:DEBUG:{'success': True, 'access': 'full'}
2022-06-20 14:39:17,953:88:update_role:update_role_permissions:DEBUG:{'success': True, 'access': 'none'}
2022-06-20 14:39:18,449:88:update_role:update_role_permissions:DEBUG:{'success': True, 'access': 'full'}
2022-06-20 14:39:19,061:88:update_role:update_role_permissions:DEBUG:{'success': True, 'access': 'none'}
2022-06-20 14:39:19,493:88:update_role:update_role_permissions:DEBUG:{'success': True, 'access': 'none'}
2022-06-20 14:39:19,899:88:update_role:update_role_permissions:DEBUG:{'success': True, 'access': 'none'}
Time to complete: 63.22
```

The json file that gets read in contains a number of api calls that are needed updating.

data.json

```
{
  "rolePermissions":{
    "roleprivs": {
      "admin-appliance": {
        "permissionCode": "admin-appliance",
        "access": "none"
      },
      "admin-backupSettings": {
        "permissionCode": "admin-backupSettings",
        "access": "none"
      }
     }
    }
}
```

The old version that i was testing was something like the following and using yaml - which yaml was kind of a nightmare to manage.
oldversion.py

```
def background(f):
  def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, f, *args, **kwargs)
  return wrapped

@background
def role_update_post(strRoleID, access, code):
    url, header, verifySSL = mApi.role()
    session.headers.update(header)
    url = f'{url}/{strRoleID}{mApi.updateRolePermissions()}'
    payload = classes.cl_payload.pl_permissionsRole(code, access)
    result = session.put(url, verify=verifySSL, headers=header, data=payload)
    response = result.json()
    if response["success"] == False:
      logger.debug("Error updating permission.  Enable Debugging")
      logger.debug(f"Result: {response}")
      logger.debug(f"Access: {access}")
      logger.debug(f"Code: {code}")
    elif response["success"] == True:
      logger.debug(f"Permission updated: {code}")
```

However this would complete the script - but push the role update to the background - and the script would complete and stall at the end waiting for the background to complete.  still took the same amount of time just not as noticeable.

Ideally - I think multiprocessing is the route i would want to do but still not quite grasping how to make that a proper for loop and multiprocess that for loop.

OR - i am just crazy and there is a much better way to do it all - and i am currently an anti pattern.

UPDATED:
so this concurrent config actually processes properly - however its still at the same speed as the other.

```
    def testing2():
        def post_req(payload):
            result = session.put(url, verify=verifySSL, headers=header, data=payload)
            response = result.json()
            logger.debug(response)
            logger.debug('post_req')
            return result
        start = time.time()
        futures = []
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
            for k,v in permissions_roleprivs.items():
                perm_code = v["permissionCode"]
                perm_access = v["access"]
                payload = json.dumps(
                    {"permissionCode": perm_code, "access": perm_access}
                )
                futures.append(executor.submit(post_req,payload)) #for k,v in permissions_roleprivs.items()
                for future in futures:
                    future.result()
        end = time.time()
        logger.debug('intesting 2')
        print(f"Time to complete: {round(end - start, 2)}")
```

Comment: `concurrent.futures` should be fine for this (making a bunch of http PUT requests concurrently) and have less overhead than multiprocessing. But you don't really show any of your concurrency code so it's hard to advise what to improve

Comment: let me take a gander at that and see what i can come up with.  I haven't looked at concurrent futures - let me read up and add some code in there.  didn't know what to use.

Comment: multithreading is ideal for this although be aware that you cannot share a requests session object between threads (not thread safe). Your logger may not be thread safe either - you should look into that

Comment: @Anentropic - added an update - still poking around and testing some other concurrent futures.  I tried to copy and paste the code in comments but its too long for the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so concurrent.futures - is the ideal sweetness that is needed to process this.  I had to do a little more testing but now a process that used to take 60 to 80 seconds depending on the server i was hitting.  Now takes 10 seconds.

```
    def testing2():
        def post_req(payload):
            result = session.put(url, verify=verifySSL, headers=header, data=payload)
            response = result.json()
            logger.debug(response)
            return result
        start = time.time()
        futures = []
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            for k,v in permissions_roleprivs.items():
                perm_code = v["permissionCode"]
                perm_access = v["access"]
                payload = json.dumps(
                    {"permissionCode": perm_code, "access": perm_access}
                )
                futures.append(executor.submit(post_req,payload)) #for k,v in permissions_roleprivs.items()
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                future.result()
        end = time.time()
        logger.debug('intesting 2')
        print(f"Time to complete: {round(end - start, 2)}")
```

One of the key screw ups that i found in my previous attempts at this was

```
for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                future.result()
```

I didn't have this line of code - properly setup or in my initial tests it didn't exist.  When i finally got this working - i was still seeing 60 seconds.

The next problem was it was in the for loop for roleprivs.items() - pulled that out of the initial for loop and was able to process much faster.

Comment: Review this before sharing a Session between threads in a production environment:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188044/is-the-session-object-from-pythons-requests-library-thread-safe

Comment: Clearly, in your original coding the statements `for future in futures: future.result()` was indented at the wrong level. That is, you were submitting a task but then immediately waiting for it to complete prior to submitting the next task. So you never had more than one `put` request running concurrently. By the way, I could not see `permissions_roleprivs` idefined in any of your coding posts. Did I miss something?