# can using multiple threads in python and sending a POST request to the same api endpoint cause problems?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm currently using 3 threads to run my django app and I've noticed sporadic errors in the return response from a POST request that I'm making that uploads some info unto a database.
`responseObject = requests.post(url, params=params)`
I'll get an error back saying that "the entry already exists",now I don't control this endpoint myself so I can't look into it but I guess that particular message is irrelevant since I make sure that each request is different and also the error appears randomly and I can't really replicate it. I have ruled out anything wrong with the parameters, url or anything like that in this case.

My suspicion is that the error comes from the threads making the request at the same time or something like that. Now I've read that django is supposedly thread safe and that the requests library in python is also thread safe so I don't know why it would cause trouble, I don't think these 3 requests would cause any trouble for the endpoint as a server is most likely made to handle concurrent web requests? I have tried making this request under a lock like

```
lock = threading.Lock()
with lock:responseObject = requests.post(url, params=params)
```

and so far I haven't gotten the error. Though my knowledge of this is limited so I'm not really sure if I'm doing anything to solve the problem here.

As I mentioned I tried adding the lock and only doing the request.post inside that scope which I think means that only 1 thread can do it at a time. So far the error has not occured. But I'm not sure whether that really makes a difference since it's only 3 threads and thus 3 requests and web servers can take on thousands of requests.

Comment: It turns out that this question is really difficult to answer... By making some further research on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20457621/14956120), and others on the same page, sharing a single session object on multiple threads is a bad idea. From what I've found so far, creating new session instances and setting each one for a corresponding thread might be considerated thread-safe (even if they target the same url). Also, it's really unclear on the docs if requests.sessions are thread-safe or not. Most people tend to argue that its not safe (mostly based on the urllib3 module).